# Bash script to extract wifi passwords from NetworkManager

Tags: beginner, bash, linux

This is my first shell script, so I am trying to see if I can get some suggestions. It extracts saved wifi passwords from Linux.

```
##################################################################

# This script is used to copy wifi password files from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections folder

# check if the wifi_pass_dir exists, and delete it if it does
if [ -d "wifi_pass_dir" ]
then
    rm -rf wifi_pass_dir
fi

# Create wifi_pass_dir folder
mkdir wifi_pass_dir


#copy the files from NetworkManager to the folder created, these files can only be read by the root user so use sudo
sudo cp /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* ./wifi_pass_dir


# change the file permission from read only by root to read and write by any user (666) 
sudo chmod 666 ./wifi_pass_dir/*

#create a list so we know what wifi passwords are saved
sudo ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections > ./wifi_pass_dir/pass_list.txt

# Read name of wifi from pass_list.txt and print on screen 
cd wifi_pass_dir
filename="pass_list.txt"

while read -r line
do 
    name="$line"
    echo $name 
    cat "$name" | grep psk=
done < "$filename"
##################################################################
```

Comment: @Asdeth : Just a minor issue: Your script will produce several error messages if the directory *system-connections* is empty.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you. To be honest I don't actually know what a directory system-connect is. I will definitely look up for it.

However would you be kind enough to point me which particular line would this affect and any suggestions on what I could do differently? [I do not get error when I run in on my computer but obviously I haven't had the opportunity to have it run on anyone else's]

Comment: It's *system-connections*, and you mention it in your script, so if you don't know what it is, who else would? .... For verifying whether a directory contains files, see for instance [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-check-if-directory-empty/)

Comment: Oh now I get it. Thank you. 

So i need to add an error checking code to see if the folder is empty. Sort of like , erm, a sanity check. 

Got it cheers =)

Appreciate the input mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General

Always include a shebang, and set options to exit the script when a command fails or when we use a variable that's not set:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu
```

## Test for existence with `-e`, not `-d`

If `wifi_pass_dir` exists, but is not a directory (perhaps it's a plain file), it will not be deleted, and the `mkdir` will fail.  It might be better not to check (`rm -f` will succeed if the file doesn't exist):

```
# Ensure the wifi_pass_dir exists
rm -rf wifi_pass_dir
mkdir wifi_pass_dir
```

However, I don't believe it's necessary to copy the config files to an insecure location and make them world readable (and writeable) - see later.

## `sudo` is for interactive use, not scripts

Avoid using `sudo` in a script - it expects to be interactive, and won't necessarily do what you want if not connected to a terminal.  It's easier to require that the script be run under `sudo` (and we can then use `su` to change to a non-privileged user where necessary).

## Don't parse the output of `ls`

Filenames you don't control can contain all sorts of characters, including newlines.  Here, we don't need to do that, as we're reading from a directory.  The `while read` loop can simply be a `for f in *` loop.

## Don't over-exercise the `cat`

This `cat` isn't needed:

```
cat "$name" | grep psk=
```

Just tell `grep` to take its input from `$name` directly:

```
grep psk= "$name"
```

We don't even need a loop, as we can pass all the filenames to `grep` in one go.

---

## Simplified code

```
#!/bin/bash
exec grep 'psk=' /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

Yes, that's the whole program.  Since we only execute one command, we don't need `set -e`, and as we use no variables, neither do we need `set -u`.

Comment: Toby Speight , thank you buddy.. seriously thank you. I really appreciate the time and effort you put in this. Thank you so much it really helps :)

Comment: If you found it useful, you can *accept* the answer - select the tick mark underneath the voting buttons.